# How to track transactions with mapping without overwriting previous data in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to record all the transaction details done by any address like so:

```
contract GetPayment {

    struct Payment {
        uint amount;
        uint timestamp;
    }

    mapping(address => Payment) public mainMap;

    function pay() public payable {
    mainMap[msg.sender].amount = msg.value;
    mainMap[msg.sender].timestamp = now;
    }
}
```

The problem with this code, is that every time the msg.sender makes a new transaction, it overwrites the previous data.

How to save the data without overwriting the previous data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a mapping to a dynamic array of Payments and push a new payment each time it is made?

```
mapping(address => Payment[]) public mainMap;

function pay() public payable {
    Payment[] storage payment = mainMap[msg.sender];
    payment.push(Payment({amount: msg.value, timestamp: block.timestamp}));
    mainMap[msg.sender] = payment;
}
```

That is if you want it to be accessed in the contract.

Otherwise, if you want to utilize it in the front-end, you can use an event with an inerrable element of the address to parse it.